# CSV reader problems

Tags: python, csv

I am getting a list of lists from this code, and I just want a list. What am I missing? gene list.csv is a simple csv file with one element per line. This code produces a list of each gene in a separate list like: `[['IFNAR2'], ['AKT1'], ['AKT2'], ['IFNAR1']]`

```
gene_list = list(csv.reader(open("genelist.csv")))
```

Comment: What makes you think it's a csv ("comma-separated value") file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all your file contains are *one* element per line, don't use the `csv` module. Just read the file directly:

```
gen_list = open('genelist.csv').read().splitlines()
```

The `csv` module is used to parse multiple comma, space or tab-separated values per line, and thus each line is returned as a list of columns.

If you *must* use `csv` for the file, 'unwrapping' the resulting nested lists is easy enough:

```
gene_list = [g[0] for g in csv.reader(open("genelist.csv"))]
```

That is a list comprehension, that takes the first column of each row produced by the `csv.reader()` call.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the explanation, and your first solution works well.

Comment: I think a point as to be made here for closing files; unless I misunderstood how anonymous file handles are dealt with.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: They are closed automatically. Their reference count drops to zero, are deleted by the garbage collector, and that triggers an automatic call to `.close()`.

Comment: Nitpick: "reference count drops to zero" does not imply "are deleted by the garbage collector", although that is the case in current versions of CPython.

Answer (score 2):

[csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) returns an iterator over the rows as a list in the csv. The `list` creates a list of the iterator so you see a list of list.

You might want to chain the generated row iterators using [itertools.chain](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
gene_list = list(itertools.chain(*csv.reader(open("genelist.csv"))))
```

If what you get is a single gene per row, csv is not a good option. Rather just iterate through the file and create a list out of it

```
map(str.strip, open("genelist.csv"))
```

or as a LC

```
[e.strip() for e in open("genelist.csv")]
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into using itertools. Could be very useful for my work.

Answer (score 2):

That's the expected behavior. From the csv module documentation:

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings.

Your file has one item per line, so you get a list of lists with one item. To get a list of strings, you can do this:

```
with open("genelist.csv") as f:
    f.readlines()
```

(You'll have to strip off the linefeeds from each item too.)

Comment: Thank you. I understand the csv module better, I appreciate the explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple list comprehension to read all the rows from the file. Not sure why you are using a csv reader if you only have one item per line though.

```
gene_list = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(open("genelist.csv"))]
```